# master page,web application with c#

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, master-pages

how can i access elements(like lblMessage) of master page in a page that use this masterpage? that mean i want to see elemens of masterpage in intellisense of my page.

Comment: You will be able to access the control of masterpage but without intellisense.

Answer (score 2):

Have a typed property in your page that will return reference to your master page. Let's say, code behind class of your master page has name `MyMaster` then you can add property in your page such as

```
public MyMaster MyMaster 
{
   get
   {
       return this.Master as MyMaster;
   }
}
```

Now within page, you can use this.MyMaster to get intellisense for master page properties. You can access controls from master page if you set their accessibility public (or internal protected) instead of protected (default setting) - but I would recommend against it. Better approach will be to add methods/properties in your master page that will adjust its UI as per requirement.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few good articles on the web, try [googling this](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=materpage+communication#sclient=psy&num=10&hl=en&q=search+masterpage+controls&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=3563b7a60ada09ab)

[this one](http://odetocode.com/Articles/450.aspx) and [this one](http://www.devcurry.com/2009/02/access-aspnet-master-page-controls-from.html)

Answer (score 0):

if u want the values of a label or textbox you can user the following code

ContentPlaceHolder ContentPlaceHolder1;
        TextBox txtbx;
        ContentPlaceHolder1 = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
        if (ContentPlaceHolder1 != null)
        {
            txtbx = (TextBox)ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("txt1");
            if (txtbx != null)
            {
                txtbx.Text = "TextBox found!";
            }
        }